# Error: Can't install Pandas library on Termux (2023)

Tags: python, pandas, installation, pip, termux

I tried installing pandas using `pip install pandas` and for some reason, pip couldn't see where numpy is.

I already have numpy by doing `pkg install python-numpy`

And I have proof:

```
~ $ python
Python 3.11.5 (main, Aug 30 2023, 00:13:08) [Clang 14.0.7 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 4c603efb0 on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.random.randint(10, size=(4,4))
>>> a
array([[1, 6, 2, 6],
       [5, 1, 5, 9],
       [1, 8, 5, 3],
       [2, 8, 9, 3]])
>>>
```

And when I tried to install pandas using `pip install pandas` it shows this error log (I only included the last logs):

> 

```
        INFO: Platform      :


          Architecture: aarch64


          Compiler    : clang





        CPU baseline  :


          Requested   : 'min'


          Enabled     : NEON NEON_FP16 NEON_VFPV4 ASIMD


          Flags       : none


          Extra checks: none





        CPU dispatch  :


          Requested   : 'max -xop -fma4'


          Enabled     : ASIMDHP ASIMDDP ASIMDFHM


          Generated   : none


        INFO: CCompilerOpt.cache_flush[857] : write cache to path -> /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-t7vd_qoe/numpy_9a310625fce34ac29b815ac5ab43bd77/build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.11/ccompiler_opt_cache_clib.py


        [end of output]





    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


    ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy


  Failed to build numpy


  ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects


  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.

│ exit code: 1

╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I didn't managed to install pandas by pip, however I used other method.
This is for the future 'askers' (This might not work in year 3000 tho).

First, make sure to install the necessary repos and install numpy by `pkg install python-numpy`.

Then install the tur-repo:

```
pkg install tur-repo
```

I don't know the dependencies but if you wanna know, go to its github [repo here](https://github.com/termux-user-repository/tur).

Then after you do the tur-repo,

```
pkg install python-pandas
```

That's it! I can't believe I found the answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall your np by
`pip uninstall numpy`

Restart your machine

Then install pandas first, then numpy
`pip install pandas`
`pip install numpy`

Comment: I tried installing numpy with pip in termux(mobile) and failed. That is why I am using python-numpy